# Transferring a directory contains images in RGB to grayscale

Tags: image, matlab

> Reading the content of the directory and for every JPEG image converting to grey scale

```
srcFiles = dir('R:\...\images - Copy\*.jpeg');


for i = 1 : length(srcFiles)
filename = srcFiles(i).name;
try
    I = imread(filename);
catch ME
    continue 
end
IGrey = rgb2gray(I);  
imshow(IGrey);
pathOfNewFile = strcat(pathOfGSFolder,filename,'jpeg');
imwrite(IGrey,pathOfNewFile,'jpeg');    

end
```

Comment: This loop is not being performed for some reason

Answer (score 0):

`'R:\...\images - Copy\'` is not a valid path. A folder cannot be called `...`

When trying to execute the first line you will probably get an error and the variable `srcFiles` will be empty, so the `length` of this variable will be `0` and therefore the loop will not execute.